# Lollipop activity transitions: Back button vs. back from toolbar differences?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, activity-transition

I have an app where I'm doing activity transitions for a company directory.  When a search result is selected, the animation of their photo to the detail screen works.  And if I hit the back button, the reverse animation occurs.  However, if I hit the back arrow from the Toolbar, the reverse animation never occurs.

The detail screen is a new DetailActivity with a single fragment in it called DetailFragment.  I'm not doing anything special on "onBackPressed".  Should I be?

Comment: Well the 'Up' button in the toolbar is a different operation from the back button so they aren't quite the same thing (Up recreates the next level up and doesn't resume a previous instance by default for example)

Comment: Good point.  http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html

So I assume animations should never occur when using the "Up" command, correct?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want the return transition to play, you'll need to listen for the up-navigation button click and call `finishAfterTransition()` directly:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            finishAfterTransition();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: supportFinishAfterTransition();

Comment: why does the `parentActivity` functionality in AndroidManifest actually open a new activity, instead of closing all activities between this and the parent activity?